# Get post content from outside the loop

Tags: loop, post-content

Is there a way to get the content from another outside the loop? The ID is 302 and I need to display the content of that on another page.

Comment: Don't know the ID? Make use of `get_queried_object_id()` ! https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get_queried_object_id/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

#### You can use [`get_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) to return the `$post` object of a static page:

```
$page_id = 302;
$page_object = get_page( $page_id );
echo $page_object->post_content;
```

#### Edit

Similarly, you can use [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) to return the `$post` object of a post:

```
$post_id = 302;
$post_object = get_post( $post_id );
echo $post_object->post_content;
```

Comment: Do shortcodes still work when using this?

Comment: Just found out it doesn't. Use `setup_postdata( $post );` first, after that, you can use `the_content();`

Comment: You could just run `apply_filters( 'the_content', $post_object->post_content );`

Answer (score 8):

to get the content of the post outside the loop you can write something like this

```
global $post;
$content = $post->post_content;

if ( !empty( $content ) ) :
    echo $content;
endif;
```

Comment: ```global $post``` is only available inside the loop, which is the whole point of the question

Comment: No, this is available outside the loop. Its a global variable and holds the current post data. https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't clear enough. Yes, it is a global variable but note that it is under the section titled "Inside the Loop variables", which says "While inside the loop, these globals are set, containing information about the current post being processed."

If your code runs on a page before the loop, which $post is it going to return?

Also, the OP wants to get content for a post, which is NOT the current post, so it doesn't even make sense in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Was looking for the same thing, I'm surprised nobody said this:

```
$pageID = 302;

echo get_the_content(null, false, $pageID);
```

Works good! :)

Comment: Simple yet elegant!

Answer (score 3):

If your content include shortcodes, you should use:

```
$post_id = 22;        
$post_object = get_post( $post_id );        
echo do_shortcode( $post_object->post_content );
```

Comment: Don't do shortcode https://kovshenin.com/2013/dont-do_shortcode/

Comment: That page doesn't provide a compelling reason to avoid `do_shortcode` other than saying, "It might be slow" and "You can just use the function that the short code calls." Those reasons are only valid for the most trivial for the most simple scenarios. It fails when the shortcode is generated somewhere else, or if there are multiple shortcodes, or shortcodes mixed in with other content and markup. Without a compelling reason, I would disagree with the statement to avoid `do_shortcode`. This smells like [premature optimization](http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451).

Comment: And it also increases the coupling between your code and the original shortcode's code. If the shortcode's backing method is ever renamed or the signature changes, your code will break.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, building on Tim's comment above and inspired by [Stephen Harris's article](http://stephenharris.info/get-post-content-by-id/), the solution that enables use of `the_content()` is:

```
$post_id = 302;
global $post;
$post = get_post($post_id);
setup_postdata( $post );
the_content();
wp_reset_postdata( $post );
```

And hence filters get applied (paragraphs will be inserted etc.) and shortcodes work.

Comment: This almost crashed my browser :/ taking out the ampersand helps, but it's still not parsing shortcodes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, as said, the solution with `get_post` and `$post_object->post_content`, but don't forget to add a check before you use that post object:

```
function get_post_content( $post_id = null ) {
    $post_object = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( ! $post_object ) { return ''; }
    //else

    return apply_filters('the_content', $post_object->post_content);
}

echo get_post_content( $other_post_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know your target post ID (302), you may find useful this shorthand syntax that you can use out of the loop (though its performance is pretty much the same as in any other alternative method:)

```
echo(get_post_field('post_content',302));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_post_data()` function to get post outside the loop. Place this code in functions.php

```
function get_post_data($postId) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=$postId");
}
```

and then add this snippet for more control on the process

```
<?php $data = get_post_data(302);
    echo $data->post_date;     // post date
    echo $data->post_title;    // post title
    echo $data->post_content;  // post content
    echo $data->comment_count; // comments number
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply call get_the_content(postId)

```
<?php echo get_the_content($postId); ?>
```

Comment: Actually, that's not possible. First arg there is for the content when there is a more link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Answer (score -2):

use `wp_reset_postdata();` it will work.. (edited)

```
<?php 
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'posttype',
        'p' => 'post_id'
       );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

posttype can be "post" , "page" or your custom post type. Here p=302 is your post id.. Hope it will work.

Comment: Never use `query_posts` unless you need to break page functionalities. Always use `WP_Query` or `get_posts` for custom queries :-)

Comment: yes.. you are right.. It can Wp_Query as well.. same result found..

Comment: There is also the `pre_get_posts` filter, and `the_post`. So much detail.

Answer (score -3):

you can put content  in a category X and use query_post before while like this :

```
    <?php query_posts('cat=X&showposts=1'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <?= get_the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```