# Page template with different page and post content

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, page-template

I am using a wordpress theme which has a page template named `roomtypes`. I am not a php pro but as far as I understand this template gets the posts. When I add a Room type, it is created as a post with a `post_type=roomtype`.
So this template gets these posts, adds their title and a thumbnail image.

My problem is, when I create a page and enter some text it does not shows when I choose this template.
So with some digging I found out that `the_content();` function does the trick. I tried to add it and it worked:)
The matter is, I cannot use the content where I need it to be.
This is the code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Roomtypes
 */
global $wp_query;
get_header();?>
       <div class="middle-inner-wrapper" style="background:#e7dfd6 url(<?

php echo TEMPLATE_URL.get_option('tgt_default_inner_background');?>) no-

repeat center top;">

            <div class="localization">
                <p class="site-loc"><a href="<?php echo HOME_URL;?>" 

style="color:white"> <?php echo get_option('tgt_hotel_name'); ?

></a></p><p>&raquo;&nbsp;<?php _e ('Rooms', 'hotel');?></p>
            </div>            
         <div style="clear:both;"></div>         
            <div class="middle-inner">
                <div class="center-inner">               
                    <!-- This is content -->

                    <?php                           


                        global $post;
                        query_posts

("post_type=roomtype&orderby=name");
                        if ( have_posts() ) {       
                            ?>
                        <div class="title">
                        <p class="h1"><?php _e ('Rooms', 

'hotel');?></p> 
                        </div>


                        <?php $i=0; while ( 

have_posts() ) { the_post(); $i++; 
                         //$thumbnail_id = 

get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
                        // $link_image = 

wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'roomtype-image' );
                        //$link_thumbnail =  

wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id); 
                        if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                            $thumbnail_id = 

get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
                            $link_image = 

wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'roomtype-image' );
                        } else {    
                          $args = array(


'post_type' => 'attachment',


'numberposts' => -1,            


'post_parent' => $post->ID, 


'post_mime_type' => 'image'
                                    ); 
                            $attachments = 

get_posts($args);
                            $link_image = 

wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachments[0]->ID, 'roomtype-image' );   
                        }           
                        ?>              


                        <?php if($i%2!=0){  ?>

                        <div class="room-left">
                            <div class="room-

box" align="center">            

                                <a 

href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                <?php if 

($link_image[0] != ''){ ?>
                                <img 

src="<?php echo $link_image[0]; ?>" />
                                <?php } ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <a class="room-

link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php 

the_title(); ?></a>

                        </div>
                        <?php } else{ ?>
                        <div class="room-right">
                            <div class="room-

box" align="center">
                                <a 

href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                <?php if 

($link_image[0] != ''){ ?>
                                <img 

src="<?php echo $link_image[0]; ?>" style="margin-top:3px;" />
                                <?php } ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <a class="room-

link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php 

the_title(); ?></a>
                        </div>

                        <?php } };
                        }else{ ?>
                        <div class="title">     


                        <p class="h11"> <?php _e('No Rooms 

Available!', 'hotel') ?> </p>
                        <div class="title-comments">
                        </div>

                        <div class="news-content">
                            <p>
                            <?php
                                _e('Sorry, but this section 

has no rooms!', 'hotel');
                            ?> 
                            </p>    
                        </div>

                    </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>         
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php get_sidebar();?>
           <div class="bottom">
                <!--<img src="<?php echo TEMPLATE_URL;?

>/images/inner-page-bottom.jpg" alt="inner_page_bottom_image"/>-->
           </div>

        </div>
    <!-- content end -->

    <?php get_footer();?>
```

I need the content to be where I'm indicating in the code, but some how when I add

```
<div>
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

  <?php the_content(); ?>

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Things gets messy.
If I only add `the_content();` then it gets much more worse,all those posts content is shows:(
How can I add only the content of the page I use the page template?

Answer (score 1):

`the_content()` (and many others) must be [**inside The Loop**](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

For retrieving a post/page/custom-post-type data outside the Loop, take a look here:
[Get post content from outside the loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/51741/12615)

The working code, **based on your example**, would be:

```
<div class="middle-inner">
<div class="center-inner">               
    <!-- This is content -->

    <?php                               
        global $post;
        query_posts("post_type=roomtype&orderby=name");
        if ( have_posts() ) {       
            ?>

        <div class="title">
        <p class="h1"><?php _e ('Rooms', 'hotel');?></p> 
        </div>

        <?php $i=0; while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); $i++; 
         //$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
        // $link_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'roomtype-image' );
        //$link_thumbnail =  wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id);    

        <?php echo 'I NEED MY PAGE CONTENT HERE - just add the following line' ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

        if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
            $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
            $link_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'roomtype-image' );
        } else {    
          $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'numberposts' => -1,            
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
                    ); 
            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            $link_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachments[0]->ID, 'roomtype-image' ); 
        }           
        ?>
```

Comment: I pasted your code into mine but only a white page come up. Let me share the whole page because I might missed something:) I might be significat to me but you might see the problem :) I will edit my post.

Comment: I'd say you should restart from the original file. The code you pasted is quite hard to read without proper indentations.. :/

Comment: brasofilo, actually the last code is the origilan one. I have used codepag.org agani, maybe it looks better. http://codepad.org/9NPqW4sn what do you think?

Comment: [Searching for the error...](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Call+to+undefined+function+get_header%28%29). But now your problem is not `the_content()`?, because I can't see it in that paste.

Comment: Yes, I pasted the original code. I am trying to add the_content(); here http://codepad.org/umUlHADt which does not work

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_the_content()` to store the page's content to a variable (`$page_content`) and then you can use it where ever you need it. If you use it inside your loop for the posts, use something like `if ( $i == 0 ) echo $page_content` so it'll only be shown once:

```
<div class="middle-inner">
    <div class="center-inner">           
        <!-- This is content -->            
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $page_content = get_the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php
        global $post;
        query_posts("post_type=roomtype&orderby=name");
        if ( have_posts() ) {       
        ?>
        <div class="title">
        <p class="h1"><?php _e ('Rooms', 'hotel');?></p> 
        </div>

        <?php echo $page_content; ?>

        <?php $i=0; while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); $i++; 
         //$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
        // $link_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'roomtype-image' );
        //$link_thumbnail =  wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id);    

        if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
            $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
            $link_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'roomtype-image' );
        } else {    
          $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'numberposts' => -1,            
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
                    ); 
            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            $link_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachments[0]->ID, 'roomtype-image' ); 
        }           
        ?>
```

Comment: Tried your code as well, the page came normally but nothing from the page_content(); function. I even tried to embed it in a div, div came in the code but nothing was inside the div:(

Comment: @cevizmx - I've updated my post. I had assumed that you were already using the page's loop somewhere.