# Get post content from outside the loop with plugin shortcode usability

Tags: plugins, loop, shortcode, content, pages

This is great for showing just the raw content...
[Get post content from outside the loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51741/get-post-content-from-outside-the-loop)
But i'd also like to apply shortcodes from various plugins to my content to affect the content.
What would I need to do to allow this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this with much less code:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id) );
```

You can also use [`get_post_field`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field) function to get other fields like `post_title`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This works...

```
<?php
$post_id = 956; // <<<< change page id here
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $queried_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: Any info, why you replace `]]>`?